# Thinking of a coordinate geometry proof on Pythagoras' Theorem with Euclid's idea but two squares only

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, analytic-geometry

Recently my colleague and I were thinking of a coordinate geometry proof on Pythagoras' Theorem with Euclid's idea but two squares only. But we are not sure whether it is an old idea or not and would like to share to you guys.

[image]

The proof is as follows:

It is known that *O* is the origin, *OADH* and *OFED* are two squares. The coordinates of *D* are (a,b). By rotating *D* anti-clockwise 90 degrees about *O* to *F*, we have *F* (-b,a) and rotating *E* clockwise 90 degrees about *F* to *O*, we have *E* (a-b, a+b).

Now, the area of the square *OADH* is b^2. Note that triangle *OHF* and triangle *OAD* are congruent (or image by rotation), and area of triangle *OHF* is half of the area of the square *OADH*, while area of triangle *OAD* is half of the area of the rectangle *OBCD*, so the area of the rectangle *OBCD* = area of the square *OADH* = b^2.

Similarly, we can verify the area of the rectangle *BFEC* is a^2. So, combining we have *OF^2* = a^2+b^2 = *OA^2* + *AF^2*. QED

Please let us know if you have any further ideas or comments on this proof!

Comment: This is exactly the proof in Euclid. The only thing you are missing is HF which allows you to use SAS between HOF and AOD.

Comment: @martycohen Yes, this extracts from Euclid's proof but without the third square and use coordinates and rotation to replace.